# Ubuntu on external drive

Tags: linux, ubuntu, external-hard-drive

Can I put a full version of Ubuntu on an external hard drive and boot off of that hard drive and ignore the built in one. So I dont have to partion drives for dual boot but can boot just from a Ubuntu drive.

Comment: You can, but you need to tell the BIOS that you want to boot off the external drive instead of the inbuilt one. Some brands (Toshiba) make it easy for you by displaying in graphical form the media to boot from at boot time, allowing you to bypass having to invoke and modify the BIOS. But not all brands and BIOS support that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, in two different ways:

1. Permanently install Ubuntu to an external drive, such as a removable HDD or even a large flash drive. To do this, you will need to change the "BIOS" (UEFI) boot order to check USB before the internal HDD. You can probably leave UEFI boot enabled but disable *Quick Boot* for the installation (and re-enable it afterwards). If the external disk is unplugged, it should boot to the current OS.
2. Install the grub bootloader on the internal disk, but specify an external HDD for the Ubuntu ext4 partition. This allows you to keep the boot order as internal HDD first, but requires modifying its boot partition.

See [AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/541034/how-to-dual-boot-ubuntu-from-an-external-hdd-with-the-ability-to-boot-to-window) for more information.